# Что за Команда sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Tags: linux, cmd, администрирование, консоль

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  что она ставит?

Comment: Тут правда нет ничего общего с `apt-get` вы запросили описание пакета, и его содержания, этот пакет может быть так же и на других дистрибутивах где нет пакетного менеджера `apt-get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как описано в `apt-show software-properties-common`

> Это программное обеспечение обеспечивает абстракцию используемых репозиториев apt. 
>   Это позволяет вам легко управлять своими
>   дистрибутивами и независимыми поставщиками программного обеспечения.

На практике это означает, что он предоставляет некоторые полезные скрипты для добавления и удаления PPA:

```
$ dpkg -L software-properties-common | grep 'bin/'
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository
/usr/bin/apt-add-repository
```

плюс резервные копии DBUS, чтобы сделать то же самое с помощью программного обеспечения и обновлений GUI.

Без него вам нужно будет добавлять и удалять репозитории (например, PPA) вручную путем редактирования `/etc/apt/sources.list` и / или любых вспомогательных файлов в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`